# Checkbox as3 function

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

I have 16 checkboxes and I need to see which of them was selected. Is there a function that can do that ?
I am able to do them with if() but it will be way to long thanks for the help !!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put your checkboxes in an array, then create a function to iterate over the array and see which box was selected (you can use "for each" and "if").  Add all selected ones to a new array and use this as the function's return value.

Comment: Even better, put them in a Vector.<CheckBox> so that it is completely typesafe.

Comment: +1 for vectors. And then check out `.filter()` for crunchy goodness. `var selectedCheckboxes = checkboxVector.filter(function(cb:Checkbox, i:int, v:Vector.<Checkbox>):Boolean { return cb.selected; });`

Answer (score -2):

You should enumerate checkboxes with progressive index, so you can cycle them with a simple for.
For example:

```
//Your checkboxes
var cb1:CheckBox = new CheckBox();
addChild(cb1);
var cb2:CheckBox = new CheckBox();
addChild(cb2);
var cb3:CheckBox = new CheckBox();
addChild(cb3);
var cb4:CheckBox = new CheckBox();
addChild(cb4);
var cb5:CheckBox = new CheckBox();
addChild(cb5);
...

private function getSelectedCb():Array
{
    var returnArray:Array = new Array();
    for(var i:uint = 1; i < 6; i++)
    { 
        var c:CheckBox = this["cb" + i] as CheckBox;
        if(c != null && c.selected)returnArray.push(c);
    }
    return returnArray;
}
```

Function `getSelectedCb()` return array containing all selected checkboxes.

I hope this could be usefull to you!

Comment: This is a bad solution because the errors introduced by it will only be handled at runtime.

Comment: According to me depends by advantage that an approch like this bring to your application. It's wrong consider a solution bad in a absolute manner!

Comment: @MatteoVinci dude, this is a bad idea.