# Verify if the checkbox are selected

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, checkbox, selected

i'm developing a simple program in flash...and i got an issue with checkboxes...i already searched here and i found one topic saying what i need, but i don't understood how to do it.

This is the question
[Checkbox as3 function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7955198/checkbox-as3-function)

Similar to this question...i need to verify if my 232 checkboxes are selected...even if a button is pressed or if it is selected.

Anyone can help me?

```
var select:Array = new Array();
var perguntas:Array = new Array("Ch1","Ch2","Ch3","Ch4","Ch5","Ch6","Ch7","Ch8","Ch9","Ch10",);
var resposta1:Array = new Array("1","0","1","0","0","0","0","0","1","1"."0");
var resposta2:Array = new Array("1","1","0","1","0","1","0","1","0","1","1");
var resposta3:Array = new Array("1","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0");
var resposta4:Array = new Array("0","1","0","0","0","0","1","0","1","1","0");
var i:Number;
var p1:Number;
var p2:Number;
var p3:Number;
var p4:Number;


    //Create all the Checkbox
    for(i = 0; i < perguntas.length; i++) {
        select[i] = new CheckBox();
        select[i].y = (i * 20);
        **select[i].addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, seleciona);**
        select[i].label = perguntas[i];
        select[i].width = 600;
        addChild(select[i]);
    }

    //Verify if the checkbox are selected.
    function seleciona(e:MouseEvent):void {
        for(var count:Number = 0; count < select.length; count++){      
        if (select[count].selected == true ){
            p1 += Number(resposta1[count]);
            p2 += Number(resposta2[count]);
            p3 += Number(resposta3[count]);
            p4 += Number(resposta4[count]);
            trace(p1);
        }else{
            trace(p1);
            trace(p2);
            trace(p3);
            trace(p4);
        }
    }
}
```

So i already found the solution using a button event...hard for me to set a event for every checkbox...so let's simplify

```
calcula.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, selecionaTeste);
function selecionaTeste(e:MouseEvent):void {
    for(var count:Number = 0; count < select.length; count++){      
        if (select[count].selected == true ){
            p1 += Number(resposta1[count]);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you just need to check if ALL of them are selected or not you can do the following:

```
var allSelected:Boolean = true;

for(var i=0; i<select.length;i++)
{
 if (select[i].selected == false)
 {
   allSelected = false;
 }
}

if(allSelected == true)
{
  trace("All Checkboxes are Selected!");
}
else
{
  trace("Some or All Checkboxes are left unchecked");
}
```

Comment: Hi yawar...i updated the code. What i need is to check if the checkbox is selected...then p1 += (Number)array[i], p2 += ...

Answer (score 0):

In the event that someone wants to check a specific checkbox.. The checkbox we are checking has an instance name of 'chk_demo'. Here I am setting a global variable so it can be checked from other functions/frames. Adding the event.CHANGE will update the variable the instant it is checked or unchecked. I am using AS3 in CS5.5

```
var isDemo = '0'; // set to 0 since it is not selected initially
chk_demo.addEventListener(Event.CHANGE, demo); // Run function when checked or unchecked (dynamically)

function demo(event:Event = null):void {
    if (chk_demo.selected == true) {
        isDemo = '1';
        trace("Box is checked");
    } else {
        isDemo = '0';
        trace("Box is NOT checked");
    }
}
```